# Make Iframe accessible only through my app and block direct access through browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, iframe, browser

Is there a way to let an iframe application be acceessible only within my web app and not directly from the browser? So even if somehow the user gets a hold of the iframe application url, they are not able to access it. I have searched some older answers but haven't really found a viable solution.

FYI, I am hosting both the applications myself and therefore am in control of their networking, ports or domains etc. So I am open to options like using docker containers, nginx or anything else. The only thing I want to avoid the touch the html/javascript content of the iframe application due to multiple issues. I am open to making changes to the parent application though.

**EDIT**

I don't necessarily need to embed it as an iframe. In a gist, I have two web ui apps - `App1` and `App2`.

`App1` - is essentially a login/authentication app.

`App2` - is the core content that I want to show to the authenticated users.

How do I best architect this solution such that no user has a direct access to `App2` and only the users authenticated through `App1` can access `App2`.

Comment: You won't even add a simple script tag to the iframe HTML?

Comment: How would adding a script tag to my iframe disable its access from the rest of the browser?

Comment: You can detect if the iframe is the parent window, which means it isn't loaded in an iframe as in outside of your app. You can even add additional code to detect if there is a parent window and that its URL matches yours.

Comment: Okay. That's a good solution but here's my concern. This Iframe application's code changes quite frequently. So everytime a new build is generated for the iframe app, I'll have to add that custom script to the new version. In addition to that, I don't have access to the raw source code of the iframe app. I only have access to the final static build generated which can be difficult to edit. So my preference is to find more of an architecture based solution than a code-edit based solution.

Comment: After looking at your update, I keep coming back to updates to the iframe code itself. Can you include a server side include to the iframe app since you are hosting both? If you can simply drop in a server side include that can detect if the user is logged in? Or do you have server side code included already?

Comment: I have included the authentication in `App1` and only if the user is authenticated, they can view the Iframe and thus `App2`'s content. But this still doesn't stop them to access the `App2` directly in another browser tab if they know it's url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246421/discussion-between-asanoop24-and-imvain2).